# Can you identify this Zener diode?

Tags: identification, zener

[image]

I am looking for the part number of this Zener.

I can't find the AA marking code on st.com.

Comment: SMAJ5.0CA-TR can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image below from [here](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/389/smaj10ca-2956135.pdf): -

[image]

It's the bidirectional version that you have. I think you may not have been looking in the correct column.

[image]

Comment: thx a lot. gj my friend

Comment: @Paolo If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The SMAJ5.0CA-TR is a TVS diode made by STMicroelectronics, and is marked "AA", see table 6 on page 10 of the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/smaj5-0ca.pdf).